# Tinymce wiris plugin image mode issue

Tags: php, wiris

I am using tinymce wiris plugin for entering equations for my project. Everything is working.

The equation I entering is previously saving as MATH ML format. It had some issue in chrome. So, I had to use mathjax for fix this issue. One of the project requirement was generating doc files. It also working fine except the math-ml equation. special characters are showing the doc file instead of the equation.

I googled and found that this the wiris have a imagemode option for saving the equation as image instead of MATH ML. It worked well in chrome. But still a broken image is showing in the doc file instead of equation image. Then I checked the 
`plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=4ee7dd91304079fd072d156593cce168&cw=95&ch=42&cb=23`.

I checked the wiris and found that a png image is saving in the cache folder while creating the issue. I am guessing instead of the above showimage.php? script link as src, it is better to show the link of the generated png image.

Unfortunately I am not able to crack that part. 
Please help if you have any ideas for that.

Thanks in advance